# iOS tableView help

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, tableview

I am trying to make a tableView that will allow me to delete and add items. The biggest problem I am running into is that none of my cells will display. I'm not sure what I'm leaving out. Here's the TableViewController class

```
#import "GroceryListTableViewController.h"

@implementation GroceryListTableViewController


@synthesize groceries;

/*- (NSMutableArray *) groceries
{
    if(groceries == nil)
        [self addToGroceries:@"Groceries"];
    return groceries;
}*/
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    self.groceries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Steak", @"Juice", @"Stuff", nil];

    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addToGroceries:(NSString *)grocery
{
    [self.groceries addObject:grocery];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [groceries release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.groceries count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"GroceryListCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.groceries objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/


// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    /*
     <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
     [detailViewController release];
     */
}

@end
```

Thanks for any help. I think the problem is where I fill the list with items, but I have tried other things (such as a constructor), but they haven't worked either.
(I have edited to code to be the correct solution so the other questions were able to help)

Comment: Assuming that groceries is a retain property, you have a memory leak because you are also calling `retain` manually.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as I was actually using a method out of a book and didn't even notice that I was causing a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...although the rest of the code could use some review. ;)

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: No, that's an optional method. It will return 1 by default if you don't have it there.

Comment: Correct. If it is there, then it should return 1 or the actual number of sections. It may be a placeholder for additional development. lipd can either return 1 and check or delete it entirely, or leave it as a placeholder if the tableview requires additional complexity.

Comment: Yep, I totally forgot to erase this method (so it displays items in the list now), but for some reason only the first item in my NSMutableArray is showing up 3 times (the size of the array is 3). I figure this is just some logic error, as I was trying to follow a tutorial on tableViews and may have just botched something since what I am making is slightly different.

Comment: Change this: cell.textLabel.text = [self.groceries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Thanks Jordan! I'm still trying to get used to all the syntax.